# When the @Async method that does not receive the return value throws an exception, the exception information that appears cannot be captured

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I use AsyncConfigurer to implement asynchronous configuration

code show as below:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {
    @Bean
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        log.warn("-----------------start asyncServiceExecutor----------------");
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(8);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(16);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(64);
        executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("SpringAsyncThread-");
        executor.initialize();
//        return executor;
        return new HandlingExecutor(executor);
    }
    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new SpringAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }

    class SpringAsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {
        @Override
        public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... obj) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Exception occurs in async method", throwable.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

At this point I have an asynchronous method

schedulingService.acceptTask(task); This is a method whose return value is ListenableFuture and is marked by @Async

```
@PostMapping("processing")
    public RestResult<Boolean> acceptTask(@RequestBody Task task) {
        log.error(
                "HPC服务接到任务处理-task的linkId:{},rootId{}",
                task.getPipeLinkId().toHexString(),
                task.getRootId().toHexString());
        schedulingService.acceptTask(task);
        return RestResult.success(true);
    }

    @PostMapping("wait/processing")
    public RestResult<Boolean> acceptTaskWait(@RequestBody Task task) {
        log.error(
                "HPC服务接到任务处理-task的linkId:{},rootId{}",
                task.getPipeLinkId().toHexString(),
                task.getRootId().toHexString());
        try {
            return RestResult.success(schedulingService.acceptTask(task).get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return RestResult.success(true);
        }
    }
```

The `schedulingService.acceptTask(task)` method execution error, it should throw an exception, but only I call

`public RestResult<Boolean> acceptTaskWait(@RequestBody Task task)` will print out the exception information, but the problem is that I need to record the exception information of `public RestResult<Boolean> acceptTask(@RequestBody Task task)`. I actually use`public RestResult <Boolean> acceptTask(@RequestBody Task task)`method, but `**AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler**` does not play any role. When an exception occurs in my method, there is no information in the console.

I printed the log in the method as follows：

```
    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        System.out.println("进入异常处理");
        return new SpringAsyncExceptionHandler();
    }
```

But it has not been implemented. I think this is a problem and it is very serious. If there is a good way, please tell me how to solve it and the reason for this problem. Thank you. The version of springboot I use is 2.2.7

Comment: The async doesn't add anything here. You are directly calling `get()` on the result which makes it blocking. So you are basically adding a whole lot of complexity without gaining anything.

Comment: Of course I know that asynchronous get will make it block and lose the meaning of asynchronous. My problem is that I need this method to be an asynchronous method with a return value, and if I do not accept this return value, this asynchronous The exception of the method can also be caught and printed. At the same time, I have to call this method to perform a synchronous response. Of course, this time I will definitely print the exception, but the problem is that what I want to capture is that there is a return value but it has not been processed. Exception occurred when returning value

Comment: Just return the `Future` or if you want to do something else, add 2 callbacks. 1 for ok, 1 for nok. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html#addCallback-org.springframework.util.concurrent.SuccessCallback-org.springframework.util.concurrent.FailureCallback- or make it a completable future, do what you want and return that from the method.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have a [`ListenableFuture`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) then use it, another thing to realize is that returning a `Future` from a controller method is also supported and will be properly handled by the framework.

In this case you probably want to convert the `ListenableFuture` to a `CompletableFuture` and call the `thenApply` method to transform the result in what you want.

```java
@PostMapping("wait/processing")
public Future<RestResult<Boolean>> acceptTaskWait(@RequestBody Task task) {
    log.error(
        "HPC服务接到任务处理-task的linkId:{},rootId{}",
        task.getPipeLinkId().toHexString(),
        task.getRootId().toHexString());
    ListenableFuture result = schedulingService.acceptTask(task);
    return result.completable().thenApply(RestResult::success);
}
```

Comment: The Controller returning Future does not satisfy me. I still found ListenableFuture<Boolean> through your first answer. addCallback wrote its handling method and successfully printed out the log in case of an exception, even if I did not receive or process it The return value of this asynchronous method can be printed correctly, but this seems to have nothing to do with @Async and Spring